# How to use '\Q' and '\E' regex symbols in python?

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I thought this should work, but it doesn't:

```
import re
if re.match("\Qbla\E", "bla"):
    print "works!"
```

Why it doesn't work? Can I use the '\Q' and '\E' symbols in python? How?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Python's regex engine doesn't support those; see [§7.2.1 "Regular Expression Syntax" in the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for a list of what it *does* support. However, you can get the same effect by writing `re.match(re.escape("bla"), "bla")`; `re.escape` is a function that inserts backslashes before all special characters.

By the way, you should generally use "raw" strings, `r"..."` instead of just `"..."`, since otherwise backslashes will get processed twice (once when the string is parsed, and then again by the regex engine), which means you have to write things like `\\b` instead of `\b`. Using `r"..."` prevents that first processing pass, so you can just write `\b`.

Comment: Thanks. I'd expect do get an exception when inserting a non-supported regex. Oh wait, this is python...

Comment: You're welcome. And yeah . . . I do see why people love Python so much, but . . .

Comment: @ruakh It’s not for the regexes, believe me. :)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Python doesn't support the `\Q` and `\E` escape sequences. You just have to escape everything yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support \Q...\E .
Ref: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

But that doesn't means it doesn't support escaping strings of metacharacters.
Ref: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape