# Code a loop on a list of delimiters?

Tags: python, regex

I have to isolate parts of strings in a html file. I thought I could succeed, but the data structure is really chaotic. I am a very beginner, so regular expressions were perhaps a bad idea. I can add that commas or semicolons were not consistent and could not be chosen as delimiters. Here in any case what I did and let me begin by an example. 
Suppose that is the html put in a variable

*Example = d1 d2 some stuff some stuff some stuff d3 d4 d5 some stuff*

If the delimiters were consistent, I could recover "some stuff" that interests me with the following script:

```
for url in open("url-repository.csv", "rt").readlines():
    variable1 = urllib2.urlopen(url[:-1]).read()
    a = re.compile('d1(.*?)\"d2')
    b = a.search(vqriable1)
    if b:
        c = b.group(1)
        list_of_d1.append(c)
```

But the delimiters are not always the same in the different pages I have to analyze, nor always in the same order.

*Example2 = d2 some stuff d3 **nothing** d4 some stuff d5*

I would therefore ask you two things. Suppose I create a list of all delimiters that I found in the html pages,

```
Delimiters_list = [d1, d2, d3]
```

1 Is it possible to ensure that the script looks for all possible configurations, for example d1 + d2, d2 + d6, dn + dn?

2 or at least, indicating the first term, and make the script stops the selection of the chain to the first term of the list it met?

This is a very difficult problem for me, I am aware that I may have been unclear, but I thank in advance those who would try to to examine it and help me.

Comment: You're opening a csv file, you should be using the csv module.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did not post the whole code, do you refer to the import of the csv library ? Or to a part of the csv library which could be suitable for this case ?

Comment: @user1466622 - I have updated my answer with some (attempted) Python code.

Comment: Small tip -- giving your variables more descriptive names than `variable1` or `a` is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't difficult if you use the alternation operator, `|`.

```
    (d1|d2|d3|d4|d25)(.*?)(?=d1|d2|d3|d4|d25)
```

This way,

1. you will capture the starting delimiter in case you need it, in group 1;
2. you will non-greedily capture "some stuff" in group 2;
3. and by using a lookahead assertion, you won't "eat up" the next delimiter quite yet, so that you can continue matching the rest of your data with the same regex.

See a demo of this regex here: http://rubular.com/r/DJVegfD3Ul.

***Note:** Sadly I don't know Python, so I won't try to write any code.  But it should be a trivial task to join all your delimiters into the form above.  See caveat in comment below.*

**UPDATE**

This is my first time writing Python, ever, so forgive my mistakes.

```
    # start with an array of delimeters
    delimeters = [d1, d2, d3]

    # start with a blank string
    regex_delim = ''

    # build the "delimiters regex" using alternation
    for delimeter in delimeters:
        regex_delim += re.escape(delimeter) + '|'

    # remove the extra '|' at the end
    regex_delim = regex_delim[:-1]

    # compile the regex
    regex_obj = re.compile('(' + regex_delim + ')(.*?)(?=' + regex_delim + ')')

    # and that should be it!
    for match in regex_obj.finditer(html_str):
        print match.group(2)
```

The `re.escape(delimiter)` is necessary in case your delimiters have special characters in them.  For example, if your delimiter was `*`, `re.escape(...)` returns `\*`, so that your delimiter isn't translated as a regex quantifier.

Comment: Oh, and your real-world delimiters will most likely contain special characters that mean things in regex. To get around this, escape each delimiter before joining them with ``|``: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608347/how-to-use-q-and-e-regex-symbols-in-python.

Comment: Hi This is the kind of thing that should be, too bad it does not exist directly in Python. Thank you anyway for the tra, although the curve for a beginner will be tough;) On the second point I do not know if I understood correctly, but it makes me think of what I tried: replace each delimiter with a special character. The problem was that the contents were not always in the same place. For example I had "owner" before "date" in one case, the reverse in the following page.

Comment: @user1466622 - Hm, perhaps I'm misunderstanding, perhaps you're misunderstanding.  Python regex does support alternation ``|`` so you're fully able to implement what I suggested!  Give me a few minutes to update this answer with pseudocode...  The second point will be clearer, too, then.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I test it immediately

Answer (score 0):

The following Python example should solve your problem.

```
dels = [d1, d2, d3]
combs = []
for d1 in dels:
    for d2 in dels:
        combs.append(re.compile(d1 + '(.*?)\"' + d2)
for comb in combs:
    check_for_matches(comb, string)
```

I hope you find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer ! I can not access to my whole code right now but I will test as soon as possible. I am extremely far to be an expert, and I ask myself is : does it prevent the case where d3 appears between d1 and d2 ?

Comment: the question is what do you want to do on this case? catch d1(.*d3.*)d2 or d1(.*)d3 and d2(.*)d1? also, if the delimiters are similar, it could be optimized a lot :)

Comment: Yes it's a big concern and it was very hard to be clear. I do not even know if my idea is feasible :) Suppose that the first delimiter is d1 - and I am not sure that this is always the case - the script should select the content until the next delimiter that I do not know in advance - suppose it is d22. Then the script should select the content from d22 to the next and always unknown delimiter, suppose it is d11. I have found around 25 delimiters for all the HTML pages.

Comment: well, checking for all 25^2-25 pairs of delimiters is not that good idea...
how are the delimiters built? when you say d1, do you mean the string 'd1'?

Comment: also, could you add the structure of an example page to the question?

Comment: Here are some examples from a site similar to the one Istudy, but I have no API. http://publicdata.eu/api/rest/dataset/warwickshire-public-weighbridges

http://publicdata.eu/api/rest/dataset/wms-bundeswasserstra-en-der-wsv-web-map-service
In fact my delimiters are the fields, for example the first : license_title.
At first I tried to separate items by commas, but they are used too widely. Then I turned the fields into special characters, but it does not work because the fields are not always in the same order. The goal, the Graal, is to get a csv where the fields will match the delimiters.

Comment: may i suggest you to use commas and add a backslash before each comma inside fields, then you can use this re.split(r"(?<!\\)\'", yourstring), as (?<!\\) will match only if the previous chr wasn't a backslash. or you can use pickled lists...