# Equiv of \Q \E in .NET and Python?

Tags: c#, python, regex, vb.net

PHP && Java regex let you escape part of a regex between `\Q` and `\E` like this

```
\d+\Q**(+)**\E\d+
```

This match for instance `12**(+)**22`

It's a convenience because without that you have to escape the special character

```
\d+\*\*\(\+\)\*\*\d+
```

Is there something like this in .NET?
Also same question about Python

Thank You

Comment: `Regex.Escape` works for .NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python doesn't support `\Q` `\E`. You can use `re.escape`.

See [How to use '\Q' and '\E' regex symbols in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608347/how-to-use-q-and-e-regex-symbols-in-python) for more info.