# Python equivalent of Java Regex Quotation

Tags: java, python, regex

EDIT: As already explained in the original question, `re.escape()` is not a solution for this use case. This is therefore not a duplicate of [Escaping regex string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/280435/escaping-regex-string-in-python). Please read the question before closing as a duplicate!

Java allows the use of `\Q` and `\E` to escape blocks of characters, instead of only escaping characters one at a time. [Java Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Is there an equivalent for this in Python? I've reviewed the [Python re Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and couldn't find it, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something.

I know there's `re.escape()` which will automatically escape all non-ASCII characters, but this doesn't work for my use case.

My use case is effectively taking a user-supplied string of format `foo<a>bar<b>baz<c>` and turning it into a regex that will match foo followed by a number then bar then another number then baz then another number. It would then capture the values of `<a>`, `<b>`, and `<c>`. Also, it's possible that `foo`, `bar` and `baz` could instead be strings containing regex special characters, such as in the case of `$.cities[<a>].name`.

Java code is something like this:

```
String key = "foo<a>bar<b>baz<c>";

String keyRegex = "^\\Q" + key + "\\E$";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("<.*?>").matcher(key);

while (m.find()) {
    keyRegex = keyRegex.replace(m.group(), "\\E([0-9]+)\\Q");
}

keyPattern = Pattern.compile(keyRegex);
```

Comment: I agree that the question isn't a dupe of that, but for your particular case surely `re.escape` is good enough? You're quoting the entire pattern anyway.

Comment: I'm not though. There are capture groups in the middle of the pattern that aren't quoted. See the `while` loop.

Comment: Ok, maybe you're right. I can't read Java for the life of me.

Comment: @anubhava Surely *"Does python have an equivalent of \Q and \E"* is a different question than *"How do I escape a regex in python"*?

Comment: Now [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608347/how-to-use-q-and-e-regex-symbols-in-python) might be a suitable dupe.

Comment: That does confirm my fears, yes. Thanks!